# Steps of Database Backup and Restore to Other Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a couple of Databases which I need to deploy from Production Servers to Live Servers.

What I am doing is, before creating Backup, I rebuild the indexes and Update Statistics, then make backup and send it to Live.

Is that a good practice, can some one advice me in this regard

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuilding indexes and update statistics, then shrinking make the database server busy, which may respond to your users as database server busy, or slow down their queries. Space is not an issue now a days so increase your database server drives.

Thanks